# Why we commonly use i,j or n,m as indexes in math formulas?

Tags: programming

What's the purpose (or the origin) of the use habit of **i, j, k** or for example **n, m** as indexes for math equations in general? Also this is carried into programing languajes. For example to do a simple for, we commonly use:

```
for i in rows: 
  for j in columns:
```

to iterate over matrixes. I mean, why we don't use a,b,c or e,f,g, etc as indexes?

Comment: Duplicated in other Exchanges, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters)

Comment: Also [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable)

Comment: timday's answer in the SO dupe mentioned by Mr Ripstein above has fully answered the OP's question.

Comment: We don't use $a,b,c$ or $e,f,g$ because if we did someone would post to math.stackexchange asking why we don't use $i,j$ or $m,n$.

Answer (score 4):

Back in the day, Fortran had implicit typing rules which said that a variable with a name starting with I, J, K, L, M or N would be assumed to be an integer variable unless explicitly declared otherwise - all other variables were assumed by default to be real i.e. floating point numbers (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007365fbc/index.html).

This could explain why it has become conventional to denote loop indices by *i*, *j* etc. We could use *blick* or *frump* instead but that would be unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the purpose for you with need a symbol or alphabet with which you want to denote a mathematical entity. Examples:

When we want to denote a ***number*** tend to think of the letter ***n*** because that is the first letter of the word number.

Similarly, when we want to denote a ***prime number*** number theorist usually use the letter ***p*** because that is the first letter of the word prime.

When we want to denote an ***iterative*** step/process which repeats a finite or infinite  a ***number*** tend to think of the letter ***i*** because that is the first letter of the word iteration.

Naturally when you want to denote the second iterative step/process within the same calculations we tend to think of the letter ***j*** because we have already used up ***i*** so be automatically go to the next available letter j. Similarly we have one more iterative step, ***k*** is the logically the next preferred letter.

Comment: $j$-for  jump, perhaps?